# How to prevent Outlook 2003 from updating the address book everyday?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2003

My outlook 2003 updates its address book everyday, and it takes too long and sometimes freezes my laptop. How to change it to update once a week or even better update on demand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Click the ***‘Tools’*** menu, navigate to ***‘Send/Receive’*** and then to
  ***‘Download Address Book’***.
- In the dialogue that appears, **uncheck** ***‘Download changes since last
  send/receive’***, make sure that ***‘Full Details’*** is selected and then
  select ***‘Global Address List’*** as the Address Book.
- Click OK.
- After clicking OK, you will see a ***Send/Receive*** box appear, this
  updates your local data and then disappears.

Global address list update on demand